# Erro retorno ajax quando tem acento

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tenho uma tabela que quando incluo algum texto que contenha acento some todos os outros textos daquela mesma condição. ja tentei diversas formas de usar UTF-8 que encontrei na net mas nenhuma funcionou
e eu notei no console.log() o seguinte erro somente se possui algum item da tabela com acento: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"
e se listo outra coisa da tabela (onde nao contenha nenhuma palavra com acento ) eu tenho o retorno normalmente.

> retornar_data.php

```
<?php 

    if ( isset($_POST['date']) ) {
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    } 
    $id_dentista = $_POST['id_dentista'];



    $conecta = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","odonto");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
    $selecao = "SELECT * from agenda WHERE dataAgenda = '{$date}' AND dentistaId = '{$id_dentista}' ORDER BY horaAgenda ";
    $categorias = mysqli_query($conecta,$selecao);


    $retorno = array();
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_object($categorias)) {
        $retorno[] = $linha;
    };  



    echo json_encode($retorno);

    // fechar conecta
    mysqli_close($conecta);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver o problema de charset use a função:

```
mysqli_set_charset()
```

Esta função é usada para setar corretamente os tipos de caracteres usados, no seu caso eu aconselharia a fazer assim:

```
$conecta = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","odonto");
$selecao = "SELECT * from agenda WHERE dataAgenda = '{$date}' AND dentistaId = '{$id_dentista}' ORDER BY horaAgenda ";
mysqli_set_charset($conecta, 'utf8');
$categorias = mysqli_query($conecta,$selecao) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: muito bom cara.. eu tentei milhares de formas de setar o utf8 e essa foi a unica solução!! obrigado mesmo